# Get the corresponding column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the data set I have

[image]

I intend to get the maximum number of non working women (to the right) and get the corresponding state.

[image]

```
highestNW_women=np.max(df['NON_WORK_F'])
print(highestNW_women)
```

I get the maximum number of non working women as I intend to but I also need its corresponding `Name` (left most column in 2nd image)

As such-

```
The __Name_of_state__ has highest <num> of non working of women
```

Or how can I get the data of non working women in descending order so that I can get the top 10 states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the question:

```
df_max_row = df[df["NON_WORK_F"] == highestNW_women]
```

Second part of the question: Check [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Hope this helps. Both are untested as you didn't post a file, but should do the job